# css hover effect in magento block

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, css, html

i want to add a hover effect on an image in a magento block.
i have this code in may block:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><img title="Bank" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/infortis/fortis/custom/parsian.png}}" alt="Bank" />
```

and i want to apply this kinde of hover on its image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html > <head> <style type="text/css"> .imgBox { width: 441px; height: 248px; background: url(http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/img/water.jpg) no-repeat; } .imgBox:hover { -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc; } </style> </head> <body> <div class="imgBox"> </div> </body> </html>
```

how can i do that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a plain HTML/CSS question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different options when it comes to switching images on hover.  You can either place both images in your HTML and use a small javascript to switch them out.  Since your code is in a CMS page or Static Block you could do this (using some of the styles from your example):

```
<style>
.imgBox { 
  width: 441px; /*width probably not necessary*/
  height: 248px; /* height probably not necessary*/ 
} 
.imgBox:hover { 
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc; 
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc; 
}
</style>
<p>
    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/regular-image.png"}}" alt="" title="" 
        onmouseover="this.src='{{media url="wysiwyg/hover-image.png'}};" 
        onmouseout="this.src='{{media url="wysiwyg/regular-image.png'}};" />
</p>
```

The other option is to make the image a background image using CSS and switch the images on hover.  Using the code you already have you could modify it like this:

```
<style>
.imgBox { 
  width: 441px; 
  height: 248px; 
  background: url(http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/img/water.jpg) no-repeat; 
} 
.imgBox:hover { 
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc; 
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc; 
  background: url(http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/img/water-hover.jpg) no-repeat;
}
</style>

<p class="imgBox"></p>
```